# Unity create a project for the first time

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just installed Unity and I am trying to create a project for the first time. Now all tutorials and books I ve read say to put the data for the new project and apply create and then work from there.

But after I did that first step I only get a progress bar that says "Unity Package Manager" "Starting Server..." 
This is not mentioned in any tutorial and it is taking forever. It seems stucked.

What is this server that Unity has to start to simply create a project?

Comment: Are you trying to create project on unity servers?
Actually, you can just create blank project by name and folder, where project files will be stored.

Comment: I have no idea. I just put New, then  my location, activated 3D and maybe "Enabled unity analytics. (which is what my books said) I wonder if this last one is causing this ?

Comment: Ummm no, I tried to create another one and even open an example and it is always "starting server"

Comment: Yes, it did. Actually just turn it off. As you said, you are only starting using unity3d, better learn on empty projects without any features. You will learn them later.

Comment: I turned it off and still happening. I read somewhere it might have to do with the network and some kind of authentication

Comment: How did you launch unity3d? Registration is free, and allows you to use asset store and updates, for example. You should better register or log in with your existing account into unity3d.

Comment: I do the usual. Create a new project (it happens too if I try to open an existing sample). Then the starting server happens. I notice this happens too in my mac (in my home network) but it finishes quickly. My colleagues (in the same problematic network as me) don't have this problem. Why does unity have to connect to a server to create a project?

Comment: Reinstall the whole thing maybe ? It should not give errors while creating a new project. Just new project and your location. Also what version of Unity are you using ?

Comment: I deleted the whole thing and installed a different version of Unity,. Now it works. (there are some strange things still but it is working)